# Azure equivalent of AWS tags?

Tags: azure

Is there an equivalent of AWS EC2 tags for Azure? For example, if an account wanted to assign `name=value` pairs to an Azure machine and then subsequently query them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Azure doesn't have resource tags. You'd need to implement something on your own e.g. maintain key/value tag list in Table storage (or any other store, really), updating whenever you add/remove a resource. That's something that can be incorporated into CLI/PowerShell scripts, or if you're automating via a program, you can manage tags via SDK calls.</strike>

**EDIT Oct 2015** My original answer is outdated. Using Azure Resource Manager (ARM) for infrastructure deployments, resources may now be tagged. While these may be applied and queried via CLI/PowerShell, you may also manage tags via the portal. When you open a resource, you will see a "tag" icon in the upper-right. Clicking through, you'll see assigned tags and be able to create new ones.

Here's an example of one of my demo resources:

[image: resource tag editor]

You can also pin a resource tag to the dashboard:

[image: resource tag on dashboard]

More info on resource tags is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/), including instructions for PowerShell and REST API, and a snip from a billing report showing tagged resources.

Answer (score 3):

Azure now supports tagging on preview (new) portal.
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-redis-cache-disaster-recovery-to-azure-tagging-support-elastic-scale-for-sqldb-docdb

Answer (score 2):

Tags are now available in Azure Portal Preview and can be also managed using PowerShell

Using tags to organize your Azure resources : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/

PowerShell cmlet to manage tags :

- Get-AzureTag
- New-AzureTag
- Remove-AzureTag

Regards

Stanislas